How to implement a license mechanism in a sidecar container to stop the application container on license validation failure?
I am working on a Kubernetes(v1.31.2) setup where I have an application container and a sidecar container. The sidecar container is responsible for validating a license. If the license validation fails, I want to ensure that the application container cannot continue to work.
This Python script is just a sample. It periodically sends requests to the license server to check if the license has expired. The sidecar container will shut down after sys.exit(1), but the application container will continue to run.
import os
import sys
import time
import requests

LICENSE_SERVER_URL = os.getenv("LICENSE_SERVER_URL", "")  # URL for the license service
LICENSE_TOKEN = os.getenv("LICENSE_TOKEN", "")
CHECK_INTERVAL = 60  # Check every 60 seconds

def validate_license():
    """Request the license issuer service to validate the token."""
    response = requests.get(f"{LICENSE_SERVER_URL}/validate_license/{LICENSE_TOKEN}")
    if response.status_code == 200 and response.json().get("status") == "valid":
        print("License validation successful.")
        return True
    else:
        print("License validation failed.")
        return False

def main():
    if not LICENSE_TOKEN:
        print("No license token found. Exiting.")
        sys.exit(1)

    while True:
        if not validate_license():
            print("License is invalid. Terminating pod.")
            sys.exit(1)  # Exit to terminate the pod
        time.sleep(CHECK_INTERVAL)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This is the YAML for the pod I am currently using.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: licensed-app-pod
  labels:
    app: licensed-app
spec:
  initContainers:
    - name: license-verifier
      image: localhost:5000/license_verifier:0.1 # Replace with your actual image for license verification
      restartPolicy: Always
      env:
        - name: LICENSE_TOKEN
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: license-secret
              key: token
        - name: LICENSE_SERVER_URL
          value: "http://license-server-service:5000" # URL for the license issuer service
      # Periodic check for license validity
      command: ["python", "/app/license_verifier.py"]
  containers:
    - name: application
      image: nginx:latest
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      env:
        - name: LICENSE_TOKEN
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: license-secret
              key: token
  restartPolicy: Alway

I want the application container to stop providing services when the license validation fails, without changing the code inside the application container.
Any suggestions or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

It seems like this approach would allow an operator to trivially bypass the licensing check by kubectl editing the Deployment to remove the init container.  If you need to repeat the check every minute then it needs to be its own long-running container, and I'd consider moving it out to its own Deployment.  I'm not sure how you'd do this robustly (and again protected from an administrator just taking the licensing container out of the cluster) without modifying code.

Since this is a pod, even if you do manage to stop the main container, won't it just restart automatically?

@DavidMaze Using the init container, the license is verified once the pod starts. If verification fails, the init container will exit with an error, preventing the main container from starting. However, I want to implement a long-running verification mechanism, not just a one-time check. Thanks for the suggestion; I'll consider making the verification mechanism a separate deployment.

@MB According to the YAML, stopping the main container will cause it to restart. I am not sure if a continuously restarting pod will impact Kubernetes or the entire system, but my goal is to prevent the main container from continuing to work.

@San-Zero Do you have any control over the main container?

@MB I can modify the main container, I just want to try adding the license mechanism without changing the main container.
